# PHP Парсер. Как скопированы данные отображать по ссылкам на отдельных страницах?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, парсер, phpquery

Я сделал парсер который копирует заголовки с каждой публикации на главной странице сайта. Также парсер копирует ссылки на каждую публикацию, это для того чтобы в дальнейшем парсить содержание публикаций, ну и конечно содержание публикаций парсер тоже парсить.

В результате на экране я получил список заголовков и под заголовками информацию которая находилась внутри статьи, то есть содержание публикации которую я парсил за ссылками.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы каждый заголовок стал автоматически ссылкой а информация которую я парсил отображалась по этой ссылке тоесть на новой странице?

Код парсера:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require 'phpQuery.php';

function parseArticle($url){
    $file = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);
    $text = $doc->find('.post-body')->html(); //парсинг содержания публикаций (по ссылками)
    print_arr($text);
}


function print_arr($arr){
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($arr, true) . '</pre>';
}

$url = 'http://stvorenonaukoy.blogspot.com/';
$file = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);

foreach($doc->find('.blog-posts .post-outer .post') as $article){
    $article = pq($article);
    $text = $article->find('.entry-title a')->html(); //парсинг заголовков
    print_arr($text);
    $texturl = $article->find('.entry-title a')->attr('href'); //парсинг ссылок
    parseArticle($texturl);
}
```

Comment: надо куда-то сохранить спарсенное, и затем скриптом выводить из базы, делов-то.